# How to do a react hooks api call and display only one item

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a random quote machine with react hooks and I can code a list of them to appear, but I'm confused as to how to add steps to the useEffect function to get only one random one to show up.

I was able to list out each quote by mapping over them, but I don't know where in useEffect to have it pick only one quote and display it. I know how to code it for a class component, but how would I update this to reflect react hooks.

```
class RandomQuote extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
         quote: '',
         author: ''
      }
   }
componentDidMount() {
  this.getQuote()
}

getQuote() {
  let url = 
'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json'

    axios.get(url)
      .then(res => {
        let data = res.data.quotes
        let quoteNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)
        let randomQuote = data[quoteNum]

        this.setState({
          quote: randomQuote['quote'],
          author: randomQuote['author']
         })
      })
   }

getNewQuote = () => { //will be called on clicking the New Quote button
  this.getQuote()
}
```

```
const [data, setData] = useState({ quotes: [
    {quote: '', author: ''}
  ] });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json',
      );
      setData(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

I just need help 'translating' from and old React to the new hooks.

Comment: Would you post code on how `New Quote button` and other relevant JSX code being rendered? Or possibly a runnable sample thereof

Comment: Why are you "translating" to hooks? There's no gain really. That's not why hooks were created and class components are not deprecated either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the full "translation" to React Hooks:

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const RandomQuote = props => {
    const [quote, setQuote] = useState("");
    const [author, setAuthor] = useState("");

    function getQuote() {
        const url =
            "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json";

        axios.get(url).then(res => {
            const data = res.data.quotes;
            const quoteNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
            const randomQuote = data[quoteNum];

            setQuote(randomQuote.quote);
            setAuthor(randomQuote.author);
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getQuote();
    }, []);

    const onButtonClick = useCallback(event => {
        getQuote();
    }, []);

    return <button onClick={onButtonClick} />;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the full translation!

Comment: Just trying to understand, why would you need `useCallback` wrapper? It seems re-rendering will still create new function: `setQuote`, `setAuthor` and `getQuote` all will be new function and useCallback will call OLD function that was created during first render

Comment: @Rikin You would not "need" it necessarily, but the button component is just an example (it could be anything), and imho its not good practice to pass new references down, since you cannot know if the components down the tree use `React.memo` or not.

Comment: components down the pipeline will change regardless of usage of `React.memo` as you are going to pass in new reference which possibly may be your intention to update latest instead of OLD render, but this thing is still new to wrap my head around it so its time for some more digging in `useCallback`

Comment: @Rikin I cannot conlude what you mean with "OLD render". Without `useCallback` the `onClick` property of button would change on each render, with it it stays the same for all times. Since `getQuote` is not dependent on any other values, we use `[]` as second argument. If the button takes advantage of that or not is another question.